# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: CLSBetaController block invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Hello Guys I have updated the pod files today in my projects and I saw Crashlytics got updated from 3.8.3 to 3.8.4. After installation I am trying to run the project but I am seeing this error & unable to build the project.

In Terminal

```
Installing Crashlytics 3.8.4 (was 3.8.3)
```

In Xcode Issues

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_FABNetworkMaximumRetryCount", referenced from:
      ___51-[CLSBetaController loadUpdateWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke in Crashlytics(CLSBetaController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `Podfile` Source code

Remove the fabric & Crashlytics pods

```
pod 'crashlytics' 
pod 'Fabric'
```

Install pods

```
pod install
```

Both Fabric and crashlytics pods will be removed.
Open the `Podfile` once again and Add both pods as shown below

```
pod 'crashlytics' 
pod 'Fabric'
```

Install pods once again

```
pod install
```

`Finally update Run script

Select Project >> Select Target >> Build Phrases >> Under Run Script

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" YOUR_API_KEY YOUR_BUILD_SECRET
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you open the .xcworkspace file not the project (.xcodeproj) file when working with pods. That should solve the issue with linking.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Follow all the instructions: Bring in the 2 Frameworks, Add to the plist, add the Run Phrase script, but don't add:

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

Clean and Build the project. This time it should work OK. No "_FABNetworkMaximumRetryCount" error

Then add back in:

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and now build again. For some reason that worked for me.